# SQL SERVER: How to select data when its contain null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following query but getting some issues...

EmployeeDomainName, ManagerName, TaskID, ProgramID, DepartmentID, ProgramOwner, CostCenter are the parameters allowing multiple values

My problem is ProgramId, ProgramName, ProgramOwner, CostCenter it can be null so that when these fields are null and I apply following  where condition

```
AND ProgramOwner IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(null,ProgramOwner),',')) 
AND ProductFamily IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProductFamily,ProductFamily),','))
AND  CostCenter IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InCostCenter,CostCenter),','))
```

then the data contains null values that are not showing in the output and when I comment these two where conditions then data is showing.
So How can I manage when ProgramId, ProgramName, ProgramOwner, CostCenter contains null values

```
       `declare   @InFromDate           DATETIME =  N'06/06/2019',
@InToDate             DATETIME= N'11/21/2019',
@InEmployeeDomainName NVARCHAR(50) = null,
@InBillableType          NVARCHAR(10) =null,
@InLogStatus              NVARCHAR(10) =null,
@InManagerName        NVARCHAR(max) =null,
@InTaskID             NVARCHAR(max) =null,
@InProgramID          NVARCHAR(max) =null,
@InProgramOwner       NVARCHAR(max) =null,
@InProductFamily      NVARCHAR(max) =null,
@InCostCenter         NVARCHAR(max)=null,
@InDepartmentID       NVARCHAR(max) =null



Select 
        prog.ProgramID,
        prog.ProgramName,
        prog.ProgramOwner, 
        ProductFamily,
        CostCenter,
        DepartmentName,
        logmaster.EmployeeCode,
        logmaster.EmployeeName,
        logmaster.EmployeeDomainName,
        ManagerName,
        logs.TaskID,
        TaskName,
        (CASE  WHEN IsBillable = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsBillable = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsBillables ,
        (CASE  WHEN IsMachineCostInvolve = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsMachineCostInvolve = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsMachineCostInvolve,
        MachineCostPerHour,
        (CASE When IsMachineCostInvolve = 1  then (MachineCostPerHour * sum(LoggedHours)) else null END) as MachineCost,
        (CASE  WHEN IsResourceCostInvolve = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsResourceCostInvolve = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsResourceCostInvolve, 
        rcost.HourlyResourceCost,
        (CASE When IsResourceCostInvolve = 1  then ( rcost.HourlyResourceCost * sum(LoggedHours)) else null END) as TotalResourceCost,
        sum(LoggedHours) TotalHrs ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prog.ProgramID ) AS Row


    from [dbo].defProgramMaster prog right outer join datTaskLogTransactionDetails logs 
    ON prog.ProgramID = logs.ProgramID 
    inner JOIN datTaskLogMaster logmaster ON logmaster.TaskLogID = logs.TaskLogID 
    INNER JOIN defTaskMaster taskmaster ON  taskmaster.TaskID= logs.TaskID 
    left outer JOIN defResourceCosts rcost on  rcost.EmployeeCode =logmaster.EmployeeCode and rcost.DepartmentID= logmaster.DepartmentID

WHERE LogDate BETWEEN  convert(varchar(10), @InFromDate, 23) AND convert(varchar(10), @InToDate, 23) 
    AND IsBillable = ( CASE WHEN @InBillableType IS NULL THEN IsBillable ELSE @InBillableType  END) 
    AND LogStatus = ( CASE WHEN @InLogStatus IS NULL THEN LogStatus ELSE @InLogStatus  END) 
    AND logmaster.EmployeeDomainName  IN ( (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InEmployeeDomainName,EmployeeDomainName),',')))
    AND logmaster.ManagerName IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InManagerName,ManagerName),','))
    AND logs.TaskID IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InTaskID,logs.TaskID),','))
    AND logs.ProgramID IN (SELECT Item  from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProgramID,logs.ProgramID),','))
    AND ProgramOwner IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(null,ProgramOwner),',')) 
    AND ProductFamily IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProductFamily,ProductFamily),','))
    AND  CostCenter IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InCostCenter,CostCenter),','))
    and logmaster.DepartmentID IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InDepartmentID,logmaster.DepartmentID),','))


    group by 
    prog.ProgramID,
    prog.ProgramName,
    prog.ProgramOwner,
    prog.ProductFamily,
    CostCenter,
    DepartmentName,
    logmaster.EmployeeCode,
    logmaster.EmployeeName,
    logmaster.EmployeeDomainName,
    ManagerName,
    logs.TaskID,
    TaskName,
    IsBillable,
    IsMachineCostInvolve,
    MachineCostPerHour,
    IsResourceCostInvolve,
    HourlyResourceCost,
    IsMachineCostInvolve,
    IsResourceCostInvolve`
```

Comment: Don't use `IN` use `EXISTS`. `NULL IN (1,2,NULL)` is never going to return true, but you *can* use an `EXISTS` to check if the values are the same or both `NULL`.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't pass loads of delimited lists, this seems like a better choice for a table-type parameter, and some joins.

Comment: Why do you have expressions like `ISNULL('nikhil,sai',prog.ProgramOwner)`? `'nikhil,sai'` can **never** be `NULL`, it's a literal string.

Comment: @Larnu check this query now for better understand.

Comment: I already understood your query, @NikhilJojare . That's why I made the comments I did, as what you *have* done doesnr really make sense; like checking if a non-`NULL` literal string is `NULL`.

Comment: The biggest issue here is passing delimited strings. This is an xy problem you are trying to solve. You should abandon this approach and instead pass in table valued parameters. Then you can simply join to your passed in values instead of all these crazy SplitString calls. And what is that function anyway? That isn't the native one. Does that contain loops? I suspect it likely does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created #temp Table, and use IFNULL function if the data is null then I replaced with 1

```
 ISNULL(prog.ProgramOwner,1) ProgramOwner, 
 ISNULL(ProductFamily,1) ProductFamily,
 ISNULL(CostCenter,1) CostCenter ,
```

after that I use case, If data is 1 then show table inserted data

```
case when ProgramOwner ='1' then NULL else ProgramOwner end as ProgramOwner,    
case when ProductFamily ='1' then NULL else ProductFamily end as ProductFamily, 
case when CostCenter ='1' then NULL else CostCenter end as CostCenter,
```

Here is the query

```
Declare    @InFromDate           DATETIME = '2019-08-01',
@InToDate             DATETIME= '2019-08-31',
@InEmployeeDomainName NVARCHAR(50) =  null,--'C3ITDOMAIN\test3',--'C3ITDOMAIN\test3,C3ITDOMAIN\test7'
@InBillableType       INT = null,
@InLogStatus         INT = null,
@InManagerName        NVARCHAR(max) = null,--'Test Two',-- 'Test Two',
@InTaskID             NVARCHAR(max) = null,--'2039,2040',-- '2039,2040',
@InProgramID          NVARCHAR(max) = null,--null,-- '1024,2015',
@InProgramOwner       NVARCHAR(max) = null,--'Dhiraj kulkarni',-- 'Dhiraj kulkarni',
@InProductFamily      NVARCHAR(max) =  'cipla',--'Woodies',-- 'Woodies',
@InCostCenter         NVARCHAR(max) = null,--'ABD',-- 'ABD',
@InDepartmentID       NVARCHAR(max) = null,-- '2',
@InPageSize           BIGINT        = 10,           
@InPageIndex          INT           = 2,
@InSortingKey         VARCHAR(100)  = 'ROW',
@InIsAscending        TINYINT       = 2 



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Panging_Data_List') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Panging_Data_List



CREATE TABLE #Panging_Data_List
(ProgramID          [INT],
ProgramName         [nvarchar](max),
ProgramOwner        [nvarchar](max),
ProductFamily       [nvarchar](max),
CostCenter          [nvarchar](max),
DepartmentName      [nvarchar](max),
EmployeeCode        [nvarchar](max),
EmployeeName        [nvarchar](max), 
EmployeeDomainName  [nvarchar](max), 
ManagerName         [nvarchar](max), 
TaskName            [nvarchar](max), 
IsBillable          [nvarchar](max), 
IsMachineCostInvolve[nvarchar](max), 
MachineCostPerHour  DECIMAL(18,2),
MachineHours        DECIMAL(18,2),
MachineCost         DECIMAL(18,2),
IsResourceCostInvolve [nvarchar](max), 
HourlyResourceCost  DECIMAL(18,2),
TotalResourceCost   DECIMAL(18,2),
TotalHrs            DECIMAL(18,2),
[Row]                [INT],             
)


;WITH CTE AS
(
Select 
        prog.ProgramID,
        prog.ProgramName,
        ISNULL(prog.ProgramOwner,1) ProgramOwner, 
        ISNULL(ProductFamily,1) ProductFamily,
        ISNULL(CostCenter,1) CostCenter ,
        DepartmentName,
        logmaster.EmployeeCode,
        logmaster.EmployeeName,
        logmaster.EmployeeDomainName,
        ManagerName,
        TaskName,
        (CASE  WHEN IsBillable = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsBillable = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsBillable ,
        (CASE  WHEN IsMachineCostInvolve = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsMachineCostInvolve = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsMachineCostInvolve,
        MachineCostPerHour,
        sum(logs.MachineHours) MachineHours,
        (CASE When IsMachineCostInvolve = 1  then (MachineCostPerHour * sum(MachineHours)) else null END) as MachineCost,
        (CASE  WHEN IsResourceCostInvolve = 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN IsResourceCostInvolve = 0 THEN 'NO' END) as IsResourceCostInvolve, 
        rcost.HourlyResourceCost,
        (CASE When IsResourceCostInvolve = 1  then ( rcost.HourlyResourceCost * sum(LoggedHours)) else null END) as TotalResourceCost,
        sum(logs.LoggedHours) TotalHrs ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prog.ProgramID ) AS Row


    from [dbo].defProgramMaster prog 
    left outer join datTaskLogTransactionDetails logs 
    ON prog.ProgramID = logs.ProgramID 
    inner JOIN datTaskLogMaster logmaster 
    ON logmaster.TaskLogID = logs.TaskLogID 
    Left JOIN defTaskMaster taskmaster 
    ON  taskmaster.TaskID= logs.TaskID 
    left outer JOIN defResourceCosts rcost 
    on  rcost.EmployeeCode =logmaster.EmployeeCode and rcost.DepartmentID= logmaster.DepartmentID

    WHERE LogDate BETWEEN  convert(varchar(10), @InFromDate, 23) AND convert(varchar(10), @InToDate, 23)
    and IsBillable = ( CASE WHEN @InBillableType IS NULL THEN IsBillable ELSE @InBillableType  END) 
    and LogStatus = ( CASE WHEN @InLogStatus IS NULL THEN LogStatus ELSE @InLogStatus  END) 
    and logmaster.EmployeeDomainName  IN ( (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InEmployeeDomainName,EmployeeDomainName),',')))
    and logmaster.ManagerName IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InManagerName,ManagerName),','))
    and logs.TaskID IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InTaskID,logs.TaskID),','))
    and logs.ProgramID IN (SELECT Item  from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProgramID,logs.ProgramID),','))
    and logmaster.DepartmentID IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InDepartmentID,logmaster.DepartmentID),','))

    group by 
    prog.ProgramID,
    prog.ProgramName,
    prog.ProgramOwner,
    prog.ProductFamily,
    CostCenter,
    DepartmentName,
    logmaster.EmployeeCode,
    logmaster.EmployeeName,
    logmaster.EmployeeDomainName,
    ManagerName,
    TaskName,
    IsBillable,
    IsMachineCostInvolve,
    MachineCostPerHour,
    IsResourceCostInvolve,
    HourlyResourceCost,
    IsMachineCostInvolve,
    IsResourceCostInvolve
    )

    insert into #Panging_Data_List 
    SELECT 
        ProgramID,  ProgramName,    
case when ProgramOwner ='1' then NULL else ProgramOwner end as ProgramOwner,    
case when ProductFamily ='1' then NULL else ProductFamily end as ProductFamily, 
case when CostCenter ='1' then NULL else CostCenter end as CostCenter,
    DepartmentName, EmployeeCode,
    EmployeeName,   EmployeeDomainName, ManagerName,    TaskName,   IsBillable, IsMachineCostInvolve,
        MachineCostPerHour, MachineHours, MachineCost,  IsResourceCostInvolve,  HourlyResourceCost, TotalResourceCost,
            TotalHrs,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProgramID ) AS Row
       FROM CTE 
    WHERE   (ProgramOwner IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProgramOwner,ProgramOwner),',')) 
    AND ProductFamily IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InProductFamily,ProductFamily),','))
    AND  CostCenter IN (SELECT Item from [dbo].[SplitString](ISNULL(@InCostCenter,CostCenter),',')))


select * from #Panging_Data_List
```